# how to make timeLog like Dlog (customize xcode NSLog)?

Tags: xcode, customization, nslog

Basically I want to replace occurances of

```
Dlog ("Calling computeTime");
[Tools computeTime:^{...}];
```

with something simpler like

```
TimeLog {...};
```

How can I use macro for that?

example DLog is

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DLog( s, ... ) NSLog( @"<%p %@:(%d)> %@", self, [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], __LINE__, [NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__] )
#else
#define DLog( s, ... ) 
#endif
```

I have a function like this

```
+(void) computeTime:(void (^)())block
{
    NSDate * currentTime = [NSDate date];
    block();
    DLog(@"Time Running is: %f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:currentTime]);
}
```

This function is useless because I do not know the calling function. How do we decide calling function?

I want to make this function like define Dlog

may be like that

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define TimeLog {...} [Tools computeTime:^{...}];
#else
#define TimeLog {...} 
#endif
```

but it's still error, any one can hell me to fix it?

So I can call that time log such as
TimeLog {doSomething}
and turn that into:
    Dlog ("Calling computeTime");
    [Tools computeTime:^{doSomething}];

what would the macro be?

how can I do it well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass parameters to your `MACROS` then you should use another brackets: `()` not `{...}`.